# Displaying images in a row and indicating selection - HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

### What I would like to achieve (the goal)...

I'm trying to display a row of images (with the image name below the image) in html, like so:

[image]

When a user clicks on an image I want a square to appear over the image, to indicated selection like so (user has clicked on Tile1):

[image]

---

### What I have done so far...

So far I have managed to display the tiles in a row:

[image]

**Here's the html code that produced the image above:**

```
<div id='default_tiles_view'>
    <div class="default_tiles_view_square" id="tile1">
        <img src="https://raw.github.com/andrespagella/Making-Isometric-Real-time-Games/master/img/tile.png">
        <p>Tile1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="default_tiles_view_square" id="tile2">
        <img src="https://raw.github.com/andrespagella/Making-Isometric-Real-time-Games/master/img/dirt.png">
        <p>Tile2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And the CSS:**

```
#default_tiles_view {
    width: 490px;
    height: 160px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.default_tiles_view_square {
    display: inline-block;
}
.default_tiles_view_square p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**And a fiddle showing the example above:** http://jsfiddle.net/jamiefearon/t8d6U/

---

### The strategy to achieve the goal...

I was thinking about wrapping the image and its title in a div, and then changing the background colour of the div. Here is the result and the code:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id='default_tiles_view'>
    <div class="tile_wrap" id="tile1">
        <div class="default_tiles_view_square">
            <img src="https://raw.github.com/andrespagella/Making-Isometric-Real-time-Games/master/img/tile.png">
            <p>Tile1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile_wrap" id="tile2">
        <div class="default_tiles_view_square">
            <img src="https://raw.github.com/andrespagella/Making-Isometric-Real-time-Games/master/img/dirt.png">
            <p>Tile2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#default_tiles_view {
    width: 490px;
    height: 160px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.tile_wrap {
    display: inline-block;
}
.default_tiles_view_square p {
    text-align: center;
}
#tile1 {
    background-color:red;
}
```

---

### The Problem..

It does not look good, and the actual image is not covered by the red colour. Maybe it would be possible to overlay a div over the wrap div, set it's opacity < 1 and change its background colour.

What do think? Does anyone have any ideas of a good way to achieve the goal?

Comment: Add this css...Hope this will work..:)
.default_tiles_view_square:hover{background:red; opacity:0.4; filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */}

Comment: In order to have a click event you'll have to use JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: Bill Moat - I'm aware that I need to use Javascript, the problem above is purely related to the visual aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/t8d6U/1/

So just hide the overlay DIVs initially with display:none (or e.g.  left:-9999px) then show them onClick.

CSS:

```
#default_tiles_view {
    overflow: auto;
}

.default_tiles_view_square {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;
}
.default_tiles_view_square p {
    text-align: center;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.5;
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='default_tiles_view'>

    <div class="default_tiles_view_square" id="tile1">
        <div class="content">
         <img src="https://raw.github.com/andrespagella/Making-Isometric-Real-time-Games/master/img/tile.png">
         <p>Tile1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="default_tiles_view_square" id="tile2">
        <div class="content">
         <img src="https://raw.github.com/andrespagella/Making-Isometric-Real-time-Games/master/img/dirt.png">
         <p>Tile2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken what Gaurav said in the comments, changing the opacity:

**HTML**

```
<div id='default_tiles_view'>
    <div class="tile_wrap" id="tile1">
        <div class="default_tiles_view_square">
            <img src="https://raw.github.com/andrespagella/Making-Isometric-Real-time-Games/master/img/tile.png">
            <p>Tile1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile_wrap" id="tile2">
        <div class="default_tiles_view_square">
            <img src="https://raw.github.com/andrespagella/Making-Isometric-Real-time-Games/master/img/dirt.png">
            <p>Tile2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#default_tiles_view {
    width: 490px;
    height: 160px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
#tile1:hover{
    background:red; 
    opacity:0.4; 
}

.tile_wrap {
    display: inline-block;
}
.default_tiles_view_square p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/jamiefearon/BY9Fp/

Hover over Tile1 to see the effect.